# How to disable the option time_restriction that honeypot add to the forms

Tags: forms, services, 9

In the README file for the Honeypot module, it says:

> If you want to add honeypot to your own forms, or to any form through
> your own
>
> module's hook_form_alter's, you can simply place the following
> function call
>
> inside your form builder function (or inside a hook_form_alter):

```
> \Drupal::service('honeypot')->addFormProtection(   $form,  
> $form_state,   ['honeypot', 'time_restriction'] );
```

> Note that you can enable or disable either the honeypot field, or the
> time
>
> restriction on the form by including or not including the option in
> the array.

I added this code to the `buildForm` function in the form I want to change, and also tried it with a `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`.

```
  \Drupal::service('honeypot')->addFormProtection(
    $form,
    $form_state,
    ['honeypot']
  );
```

However, the `$form['honeypot_time']` element still appears in the form. I only managed to remove it by adding `unset($form['honeypot_time'])` in my `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter`. I would like to use the way that Honeypot describes in its README file.

Comment: Did you configure honeypot to be active on all forms on the site?

Comment: Yes, it's active on all forms.

Comment: I'm just guessing that the defaults are already in effect for your form because honeypot is already enabled on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the module honeypot is that they don't explain in the README file that this code only works when you don't enable for all the forms in the site.

```
honeypot_add_form_protection(
  $form,
  $form_state,
  ['honeypot', 'time_restriction']
);
```

To disable time_restriction you must use a `hook_fomr_FORM_ID_alter()` and unset the element inise the hook:

```
  if( (\Drupal::service('module_handler')->moduleExists('honeypot')) &&
      (isset($form['honeypot_time']))
     ) {
    unset($form['honeypot_time']);
  }
```